# Nested case statements with multiple scenarios

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested, case

I have a table with two different items (A & B). The b items are the ones that are basically duplicates and must be removed or reassigned to A. I am trying to implement an output string which tells me what to do. Here are the rules:

Firstly, If the table contains only one distinct item it must be checked if it is the correct one. If it is A nothing needs to be changed but if it is B it must be reassigned to A.

Secondly,if there are 2 items it is evident that they must be either reassigned or deleted. If the date of item B matches the date of Item A it can be deleted. If the date of item B doesn't match any date of item A it must be reassigned .

Here is some sample data where I have tried to figure out the case expression logic:

```
declare @table table (
item varchar(1),
date date )

insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-01')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-02')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-03')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-04')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-05')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-06')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-07')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-08')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-09')
insert into @table values ('a' , '2019-01-11')
insert into @table values ('b' , '2019-01-10')
```

At first I tried these case statement but they gave me the wrong output for the example attached:

```
 select case when (select count(distinct item) from @table where item in ('a','b'))  <= 1 
    then case when (select distinct item from @table where item in ('a','b')) = 'a' then 'no action needed!' 
         else 'reassign to A' end
else 'delete B' end result
```

This is my second try which I tried to do with my case expressions but it fails at this point and I would need a piece of advice to make it work:

```
        select case when (select count(distinct item) from @table where item in ('a','b'))  > 1 
                then case when (select count(*) from @table a join @table b on a.date = b.date 
                        where a.item in ('b') and  b.item in ('a')) <> (select count(*) from @table where item in ('b'))
                        then 'check what overlaps and whats not' 
                        else 'delete all rows from A' end  end
    case when  (select count(distinct item) from @table where item in ('a','b'))  =< 1 
                then case when (select distinct item from @table where item in ('a','b')) <> (select 'a') then  'reassign to A'
         else 'no action needed!'  end
```

What should I change to make it work?

Comment: They are a case expression, not a case statement - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @DaleBurrell Ok Thank you. But can you actually help me with the code?

Comment: Please show your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your sample data is enough to cover all your conditions.  Here's what I would propose:

```
declare @table table (item varchar(1), date date )

insert @table values 
    ('a', '2019-01-01'), -- unique and in 'a'
    ('b', '2019-01-02'), -- unique and in 'b' 
    ('a' , '2019-01-03'), -- once in 'a' and once in 'b'
    ('b' , '2019-01-03'); -- once in 'a' and once in 'b'
```

Note that you don't mention what happens if there are two of the same date within 'a' or two of the same date within 'b'.  So I assume that this is made impossible by your interface or by your data entry procedures.

You could benefit from use of windowed functions.  These give a count of the occurence of row values partitioned by certain column groupings.  In your case, you want to get a count of the occurrence of a date regardless of whether it's an 'a' item or a 'b' item.  Then from those partitioned counts it's a little easier to write those case statements.

Watch it happen below:

```
select      *,

            action = 
                case 
                when item = 'a' then 'No Action Needed'
                when n = 1 then 'Reassign to A'
                else 'Delete'
                end

from        (
                select  *,

                        -- times row value for 'date' occurs in parent dataset
                        n = count(*) over (partition by date)

                from    @table
            ) counted;
```

For that, you get this:

[image]

And, of course, you can always automate the process.  Imagine you placed the results from the query above into a temporary table called #analysis.  You can use it in a merge statement:

```
merge @table t
using #analysis a
    on t.date = a.date
    and t.item = a.item

when matched and action = 'Reassign to A' then 
    update set item = 'a'

when matched and action = 'Delete' then
    delete;
```

Now if you `select * from @table` you will see it's done for you:

[image]